# Bottstrap multiple popover datepicker is not workimg

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, popover

First time pop over datepicker working fine, if i click second time the new popover visible but datepicker does not working

```
var showPopover = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show;
        $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show = function () {
            showPopover.call(this);
            if (this.options.showCallback) {
                this.options.showCallback.call(this);
            }
        }


var popOverSettingswithdraw = {
        placement : 'auto top',
        container : '#candidates_modal',
        html : true,
        selector : '.withdraw_i',
        trigger : 'click',
        showCallback: function() { 
             $('.withdrawndate').datepicker(); 

        },
        template: '<div class="popover" style="width: 240px;border-radius:11px"><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>',
        content : function() {
        console.log("emp");
        console.log($(this)+"lll");
            return $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.popoverwithdrawbox').html();       
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you please post your HTML and CSS too?

Comment: can you explain the first part of your code?